# php want to block for 5-minute when entered into 1 valut to array

Tags: php, arrays, block

ı have an array which has salary and name.

Salary Array:

```
 $employee = array('Mehmet' => 800,
            'Cengiz' => 5600,
            'Deniz' => 3500,
            'Sevda' => 2900,
            'Ferda' => 3000);
```

For each part:

```
 foreach ($employee as $name => $salary)  { 
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td width="80px"><?php echo $name;  ?></td><td align="right">
      <?php echo $salary;     ?> 
    </td>
 </tr>
 <?php 
  $i++;  
  sleep(5);

 } ?>
```

I only want to show one row and 5 minute later refresh web page and then first and second rows show.
Thank you...

Comment: Why don't you do the timer in Javascript? PHP is not a good solution for this, specially when it comes to timers and events in the client-side. Just create an interval and fetch the data from PHP, using AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a combination of javascript and php to do something like this.  You could do it two ways, send all the data with the html hiding the information and then making it visible after 5 minutes, or you could do it with AJAX calls that update the data after 5 minutes.

Comment: I was writing something similar, I think JS is the best way to go.

Comment: Thank you... now, we forget all other combination and focus on php only. I use sleep() or take timestamp and add second to find 5 minute. I neeed a solution like this. Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You COULD use an http refresh with a string in the URL to signify the 5 minutes has passed already.

Put this in the header

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300; url=http://example.com/mypage?timepassed=yes">
```

Then in your page code look for it like this

```
<?php if($_GET['timepassed']=='yes')
      {  
         \\stuff you want to display only after 5 minutes goes here
      }
?>
```